# Indexes in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, indexing

Can you tell us how to find out which indexes are fragmented in Oracle?  Is there a script to get a list of fragmented indexes?

And what should be done with such indexes to get performance improvement? Should they be rebuilt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by a "fragmented" index, but in general there is almost never any need to rebuild indexes in Oracle - at least, not to improve performance.

See [this article by Jonathan Lewis](http://www.jlcomp.demon.co.uk/14_index_rebuild_i.html) on when to rebuild indexes, and Tom Kyte's views [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:3035290021641) - quote:

> My opinion -- 99.9% of all reorgs, rebuilds, etc are a total and utter
>   waste of time and  energy.  We spend way way way too much time losing
>   sleep over this non-event.

Comment: The only time you should be rebuilding an INDEX is when it is invalid (eg: `SELECT status FROM user_indexes` shows it's `UNUSABLE`)

Answer (score 1):

It is more important to have current statistics for your objects