# How to tell if an oracle index needs to be rebuilt

Tags: indexing, oracle11g

When we do  massive inserts/deletes in production database, as a safety measure, we always rebuild the index. I am curious to know if Oracle gives us a way of knowing if the index needs to be rebuilt (i.e if it is up to date)

Answer (score 1):

Indexes are always "up to date" after regular inserts and deletes.

There are different operations that will make an index unusable.  For example, moving the table, some types of imports, or intentionally making the index unusable.
Unusable indexes can be found with a statement like the one below.  The actual statement would probably need to be more complicated, depending on what needs to be done
to the index.

```
select owner, index_name, status
from
(
    select owner, index_name, status from dba_indexes union all
    select index_owner, index_name, status from dba_ind_partitions union all
    select index_owner, index_name, status from dba_ind_subpartitions
)
where status not in ('VALID', 'N/A', 'USABLE');
```

But automatically enabling all disabled indexes is not always a good idea.

A process may temporarily disable and re-enable an index; you don't want to get in the middle of that.  Or a single partition could intentionally have an unusable index.
That allows archived partitions to have lots of indexes but keeps DML on the current partition fast.  Or maybe a unique constraint was disabled to temporarily allow data that violates the constraint.

There may not be a good general solution to this problem.  In a complex environment, each process needs to clean up after itself.  A developer will have to understand
these concepts and evaluate each change.

---

If your question is really about index performance, then it might be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282878/indexes-in-oracle).  To summarize:
 you should probably just leave the indexes alone.

If you think you're running into a weird case where frequent rebuilds are necessary, perhaps [Segment Advisor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17636/schema.htm#CHDHBHAB) could be helpful.